# Jquery ajax popup on dynamic anchor tag onclick

Tags: jquery

I have some dynamic anchor tags like below,

this anchor tag is in a loop.On clicking on any link,i want it to be a jquery ajax post and the div should come as a popup div.
How can i do that?

```
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"                                    
      src="ttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script?
      <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function()
  {
   $('#details').click(function()
   {   
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:      


   'http://beta.himayat.in/ilfsspringnew/trainingcentre_view/HimayatTracking/details.php',        

        data: dataString,

        success: function(response)
        { 

            $('#popupdiv').html(response);
        },
        error: function()
        {

        alert('There was an error in AJAX call!');
        }
    });
    return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: My anchor tag is <a href='#'  id="details"><?php echo trim($value['NAME']); ?></a>

Answer (score 0):

Trigger an ajax call on anchor tag click event and on the ajax success use jquery dialog.

```
$('.anchor-class').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: 'action_url',
                data: {'name': 'My name'},
                success: function(data) {
                     $('#dialog-div-id').dialog();
                }
        });});
```

Comment: my anchor tag class is details and i am passing it through ajax like you say.But it is not calling the function.my jquery function is like this <script type="text/javascript">
   $('.details').click(function(){
       alert("ok")
        $.ajax({
                url: '/ilfsspringnew/trainingcentre_view/HimayatTracking/details.php',
               
                data: {'name': 'My name'},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data)
                     $('#dialog-div-id').dialog();
                }
        });});
     </script>

Comment: Could you please insert your HTML tags and script over the question.